# Drop Down Menu with Enum values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I have been having this issue for days now and I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out.

I am using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework and I have this class:

```
namespace CP.Models
{
    [Table("CP-VIP-Preview")]
    public class CP_VIP_Preview
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Occupancy Timeline")]
        [Required]
        public string occupancyTimeline { get; set; }

        public occupancyTimelineTypes occupancyTimelineType
        {
            get
            {
                return Enum.Parse(occupancyTimelineTypes, occupancyTimeline);

            }
        }
    }

    public class Homefront : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CP_VIP_Preview> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public enum occupancyTimelineTypes : int
    {
        TwelveMonths = 12,
        FourteenMonths = 14,
        SixteenMonths = 16,
        EighteenMonths = 18
    }

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static SelectList ToSelectList(this occupancyTimelineTypes enumObj)
        {
            var values = from occupancyTimelineTypes e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(occupancyTimelineTypes))
                         select new { Id = e, Name = string.Format("{0} Months", Convert.ToInt32(e)) };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is the following, take the values in the enum occupancyTimelineTypes method (12, 14, 16, 18) and use them for a dropdown menu like so:

```
@model CP.Models.CP_VIP_Preview
@using CP.Models

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupancyTimeline,Model.occupancyTimelineType.ToSelectList());
```

However I get these errors:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' has some invalid arguments.
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from ‘CP.Models.occupancyTimelineTypes' to 'System.Type'
>
> ‘CP.Models.occupancyTimelineTypes' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

on this line in my class:

```
return Enum.Parse(occupancyTimelineTypes, occupancyTimeline);
```

I just flat out do not understand how to fix this, its been a very frustrating few days.

Comment: `Enum.Parse` returns and `object` so you seem to be lacking a cast to `occupancyTimelineTypes ` inside the getter. Also, first parameter should be `typeof(occupancyTimelineTypes)`.

Comment: What version of MVC are you running? Since MVC 5, there's been `Html.EnumDropDownListFor()`.

Comment: MVC 5 and I tried Html.EnumDropDownListFor() and it does not exist. I get an error when I try it and it has not extension method.

Comment: Didn't you solve this from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39496737/2524589 ?