# Enum.Parse Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework. In my View I have a dropdown menu and what I am trying to do is use an enum to populate dropdown menus. This is what I've got in my class:

```
    public enum occupancyTimelineTypes : int
    {
        TwelveMonths = 12,
        FourteenMonths = 14,
        SixteenMonths = 16,
        EighteenMonths = 18
    }
```

and this:

```
        [DisplayName("Occupancy Timeline")]
        [Required]
        public string occupancyTimeline { get; set; }

        public occupancyTimelineTypes occupancyTimelineType
        {
            get
            {
                return Enum.Parse(typeof(occupancyTimelineTypes), occupancyTimeline);
            }
        }
```

My problem is, I am getting an error I have no idea how to fix:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am populating my dropdown menu like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupancyTimeline,Model.occupancyTimelineType.ToSelectList());
```

and here is my `ToSelectList()` Method

```
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static SelectList ToSelectList(this occupancyTimelineTypes enumObj)
        {
            var values = from occupancyTimeline e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(occupancyTimeline))
                         select new { Id = e, Name = string.Format("{0} Months", Convert.ToInt32(e)) };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }
    }
```

I CANNOT AND WILL NOT USE `Html.EnumDropDownListFor()` as too many errors appear and its a nightmare to put in place and fix these errors.

This has to be `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Comment: Have you tried what the error suggests? `(are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: One of the few times that the error message is actually a bit helpful :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enum.Parse` returns object (it is not generic) so you need to explicitly cast your return value. Use:

```
return (occupancyTimelineTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(occupancyTimelineTypes), occupancyTimeline);
```

Comment: I wonder why they designed `Enum.Parse` to work that way. Seem awfully redundant to have to cast...

Comment: Because when the .NET Framework was first written there was no such thing as generics. The only possible return type therefore is `object`.

Comment: You'd think after all these years though they would add an `Enum.Parse<T>(object obj)`

Comment: Oh, looks like they did https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx